# creating dependent drop down list in zend form

Tags: zend-form, zend-form-select

does one have any idea how i can create dependent drop downs (Select) in Zend Form.
i.e two drop downs, country and city. city is only populated when country is chosen.
thanks

Comment: You have to do it with JS or Ajax ...

Comment: thanks. was able to do it. still looking for zend form ideas though

Answer (score 0):

In zend element (country) you have to add a attribute

```
'onchange' => 'fillCityBox(this.value)'
```

This function (`fillCityBox`) fills the city dropdown by using ajax.